# When using a random forest, should I include features that are highly predictive, but have very rare occurrences?

Tags: random-forest

I'm trying to run a binary classification random forest on a data set that has about 25,000 observations and I have somewhere around 300 features. All of these features show up at least once, but quite a few of them only occur less than 50 times in total and some of them less than 10 times.

I suspect that some of these might be perfect predictors one way or the other, but how useful are they if they're so uncommon? It would cut down on the training time of my model by quite a bit if I could remove these before I run anything. Or should I just run the model with everything and remove the least important features?

Comment: Not a programming question, more suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Build a model with them, check their importance score, if it is low drop them.

Answer (score 0):

Run one model with everything and another model without these features.

Compare the error metric for the 2 models, also check the feature importance values to see if these features are helpful.

You can also use feature selection techniques like `SelectKBest` etc from `sklearn`

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection